# Any or a trouble with sequence of functions

Tags: swift, function

The problem I have faced is that I need to make a sequence of functions that can be invoked, but faced a problem that is, even though a function is a first-class member and do conform to protocol `Any`, the code bellow does not work.

```swift
struct FunctionSequence {

    var callbacks = [Any]() //how to restrict Any to only functions?

    init(with functions: Any...){
        self.callbacks = functions
    }

    func callAll(){
        for f in callbacks {
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

Compilation interrupts with:

```
error: cannot call value of non-function type 'Any'
```

So I ask people who's deep in the swift for some help.
PS The result I need is as following:

```swift
var printer = FunctionSequence
    .init(with: {print("Hello,")}, {print("world!")})
printer.callbacks.insert({print("I hate you,")}, at: 1)
printer.callAll()
//outputs "Hello, I hate you, world!"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no general “function type” – functions with different arguments or different return types are different types.

In your case you apparently want an array of functions of type `() -> Void`, i.e. functions that take no arguments and do not return a value:

```
struct FunctionSequence {

    var callbacks = [() -> Void]()

    init(with functions: (() -> Void)...){
        self.callbacks = functions
    }

    // ...
}
```

Or with a type alias:

```
typealias SimpleFunction = () -> Void

struct FunctionSequence {

    var callbacks = [SimpleFunction]()

    init(with functions: SimpleFunction...){
        self.callbacks = functions
    }

    // ...
}
```

If `callbacks` is defined as an array of `Any` then you can put anything in it: functions taking no arguments, functions taking one integer, ..., integers, strings, anything.

It *is* then possible to check each array element for a specific signature, and call the functions accordingly. Example:

```
struct FunctionSequence {

    var callbacks = [Any]()

    init(with functions: Any...){
        self.callbacks = functions
    }

    func callAll() {
        for f in callbacks {
            switch f {
            case let f0 as () -> Void:    f0()
            case let f1 as (Int) -> Void: f1(17)
            default: break // Other function signature, or not a function at all.
            }
        }
    }
}

let printer = FunctionSequence(with:
        { print("Hello,") },
        { (i: Int) in print(i)} )
printer.callAll()
```

Comment: Got it. Too discouraging though that there is no way to define functions with signature (...)->Void, at least. That could have made my coding life much easier. Also lack of run-time introspection on functions hurts my soul hardly. Five years have passed since the initial public release of Swift, but the language still fills like it is in beta. (((

Comment: @oneWayTicket: There is *some* runtime introspection possible. I have added an example, although that is not as universal as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Use a function signature

```
struct FunctionSequence {
    var callbacks = [()->Void]() 

    init(with functions: ()->Void...){
        self.callbacks = functions
    }

    func callAll(){
        for f in callbacks {
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

or with a type alias

```
typealias VoidFunction = () -> Void
struct FunctionSequence {
    var callbacks = [VoidFunction]()

    init(with functions: VoidFunction...){
        self.callbacks = functions
    }

    func callAll(){
        for f in callbacks {
            f()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Beside the question but if you want the output on one line you probably want a function that returns a string and that `callAll` does the printing. For example

```
typealias StringFunction = () -> String
struct FunctionSequence {
    var callbacks = [StringFunction]()

    init(with functions: StringFunction...){
        self.callbacks = functions
    }

    func callAll(){
        print(callbacks.map {$0()}.joined(separator: " "))
    }
}

var printer = FunctionSequence
    .init(with: {"Hello,"}, {"world!"})
printer.callbacks.insert({"I hate you,"}, at: 1)
printer.callAll()
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem I have faced is that I need to make a sequence of functions that can be invoked

That's just `[() -> Void]`. There's no need for another type.

```
var printer = [{print("Hello,", terminator: " ")}, {print("world!")}]
printer.insert({print("I hate you,", terminator: " ")}, at: 1)
for p in printer {p()}
//outputs "Hello, I hate you, world!"
```

Comment: So it doesn't require to specify arguments for closures, ha. I was thinking that it is necessary to ```{ a, b in c = a + b }```, thus making it have different signature, which means a different types for different functions. But I sliped up.