# Is is possible to callAsFunction() variable that is Any?

Tags: swift, function, callable, any

Recently I have encountered a need of creating an Array of Functions. Unfortunately, Swift language does not provide a top level type for functions, but instead they must be declared by their specific signature `(...)->(...)`. So I tried to write a wrapper that can hold any function and later specialize it to hold only closures having `Void` return type and any number of arguments.

```swift
struct AnyFunction {
    let function: Any
    init?(_ object: Any){
        switch String(describing: object){
            case let function where function == "(Function)":
                self.function = object
            default:
                return nil
        }
    }
    func callAsFunction(){
        self.function()
    }
}
```

As I was progressing, I have found out that it is not trivial and possibly requires some hacks with introspection, but I failed to find solution, despite of my attempt. The Compiler messaged:

```
error: cannot call value of non-function type 'Any'
```

So how would you make this trick that is, to clarify, to define an Object that can hold any functional type?

Clarification:
What I would prefer is defining something like:

```swift
typealias SelfSufficientClosure = (...)->Void
var a, b, c = 0
let funcs = FunctionSequence
    .init(with: {print("Hi!")}, {a in a + 3}, {b in b + 3}, { a,b in c = a + b})
for f in funcs { f() }

print([a, b, c])
//outputs 
//"Hi"
//3, 3, 6
```

PS This question has relation to this one ([Any or a trouble with sequence of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58471473/10976864))

Comment: What is "any functional type" really? You need to call the function and if the signature is different for different functions then your call must be adjusted for each function. I don't see that in your code. So could you clarify how you want to call them?

Comment: Sure. What I want is basically an array of closures ```[{print "Hi!"}, {someExternalSequence.apply{$0+1}}, {someObject.someValue = true}]``` that can be later called at some moment during the program and manipulated if needed, meaning adding or removing closures.

Comment: There is no type that describes “any function type” (as pointed out in response to your previous question). And if there were: how would you *call* such an element if you don't know the number and type of arguments that it takes? (Objective-C solved that with the `NSInvocation` class. You probably can use that from Swift, but only for sending messages to instances of `NSObject` subclasses.)

Comment: @MartinR This AnyFunction wrapper is for proof of concept that different functions can(or cannot as seems) be put in a sequence. Later it would become a ```(...)->Void``` specific type that holds self-sufficient closures, which means those that has captured some context. ```var a, b, c = 0
let funcs = FunctionSequence(with: {print("Hi!")}, {a in a + 3}, {b in b + 3}, { a,b in c = a + b})
print([a, b, c], separator: " ") ```

Comment: I may be wrong of course, but I am fairly sure that there is no “any function” type in Swift. See also https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html: *“Every function in Swift has a type, consisting of the function’s parameter types and return type.”*

Comment: @MartinR That true, swift functions have their types as param/return type signature. So no type level for them at high level, unfortunately. But i meant exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is a mapping from inputs to outputs. In your examples, your inputs are void (no inputs), and your outputs are also void (no outputs). So that kind of function is precisely `() -> Void`.

We can tell that's the right type because of how you call it:

```
for f in funcs { f() }
```

You expect `f` to be a function that takes no inputs and returns no outputs, which is exactly the definition of `() -> Void`. We can get exactly the input and output you expect by using that type (and cleaning up a few syntax errors):

```
var a = 0, b = 0, c = 0

let funcs: [() -> Void] = [{print("Hi!")}, {a = a + 3}, { b = b + 3}, { c = a + b}]
for f in funcs { f() }

print(a, b, c, separator: ",")
//outputs
//Hi!
//3, 3, 6
```

When you write a closure like `{a in a + 3}`, that doesn't mean "capture `a`" (which I believe you are expecting). It means "This is a closure that accepts a parameter that will be called `a` (completely unrelated to the global variable of the same name) and returns that value plus 3." If that's what you meant, then when you called `f()`, you would need to pass it something and do something with the return value.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I admit that I skid.(

Comment: Also, do you know if compiler would change the execution sequence for some optimization or not? And if so, how to forbid it doing that?

Comment: No, it will not change the execution sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum to put various functions into the Array and then extract the functions with a switch.

```
 enum MyFuncs {
        case Arity0 ( Void -> Void )
        case Arity2 ( (Int, String) -> Void)
    }

    func someFunc(n:Int, S:String) { }
    func boringFunc() {}
    var funcs = Array<MyFuncs>()
    funcs.append(MyFuncs.Arity0(boringFunc))
    funcs.append( MyFuncs.Arity2(someFunc))

    for f in funcs {
        switch f {
        case let .Arity0(f):
            f()  // call the function with no arguments
        case let .Arity2(f):
            f(2,"fred") // call the function with two args
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is going to be an enormous enum and how do you keep track of the parameter values?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson they can modify my enum, means using Any instead of Int or  String.

Comment: @SGDev Still that would require enumerating every possible combination that makes that solution suitable for very specific cases. And moreover, if that must be made a framework, your solution wouldn't allow do this, sadly

Comment: @oneWayTicket  Yes, you need to specify all your use cases.